# How to get AudioLevel and Codec values from getStats() API in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, sip, codec

I am trying to get WebRTC browser stats using getStats() API in Firefox. I am able to get Jitter, Packets Sent, Packets Received etc info but I am unable to retrieve Codec and AudioLevel information. Can someone explain how to get these details in Firefox browser.

[image]

```
  cs.pc.getStats(cs.pc.getLocalStreams()[0].getAudioTracks()[0], function (results) {

    for (var key in results) {
      if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
          console.log("1. Results Dictionary: ",key, results[key]);
      }
    }

    rtt = results.outbound_rtcp_audio_0.roundTripTime;

  });

  cs.pc.getStats(cs.pc.getRemoteStreams()[0].getAudioTracks()[0], function (results) {

    for (var key in results) {
      if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
          console.log("2. Results Dictionary: ",key, results[key]);
      }
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

That does not seem to be available for Firefox yet. Callstats.io maintains an up to date state of the implementation of `getStats()` in both Chrome and Firefox : https://webrtc-stats.callstats.io/.

From the `track` item there, `audioLevel` and `totalAudioEnergy` are checked for Chrome only. And `audioLevel` in the `csrc` item is never checked.

The `codec` item also isn't detailed for Firefox.

Hope this helps!

[image]